# linux output directly to screen with java

Tags: java, linux

noobish question: I've been wondering if there is a simple way to change the output of the monitor on a linux system using java. I've found [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Linux-Framebuffer) Wikipedia article (Unfortunately in German, so difficult to decipher) that seems promising, but I'd rather avoid c. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to choose which monitor to use?

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Usually your questions will be bashed hard unless you provide a very concise question, usually with code etc. Unfortunate, but that is the way of the world. Don't let it get to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is called "Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API".

The official documentation for it is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/).

Disclaimer: I have not used it, nor do I know if it is still available/active.

Other than that you might want to google tinyPTC or PixelToaster (By [gaffer on games](http://gafferongames.com/)).

Though, these days most "performance graphics" means using a GPU, and for GPU you might want to look at [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) or [lwjgl](https://www.lwjgl.org/).

:-)

Comment: AWT full-screen exclusive mode is partially broken under GNU Linux whereas it works flawlessly in NEWT API (JOGL), which allows to choose to retrieve the primary screen, render on a single physical monitor or on a virtual screen composed of several physical monitors. There is no other Java API (even a binding) to do that, GLFW used in some other APIs is a lot less capable as you can see here: http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/monitor.html